# Add metabox to document tab in gutenberg

Tags: custom-field, metabox, block-editor

[image]

How can I add custom metabox in document tab in gutenberg?

There is documentation about adding plugin sidebar [here](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/), but I'm looking for adding custom metabox in existing document tab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution. Hope it will help you

```
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;

const MyDocumentSettingTest = () => (
        <PluginDocumentSettingPanel className="my-document-setting-plugin" title="My Panel">
            <p>My Document Setting Panel</p>
        </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
    );

registerPlugin( 'document-setting-test', { render: MyDocumentSettingTest } );
```

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/edit-post/src/components/sidebar/plugin-document-setting-panel/index.js#L86

Comment: this should be an accepted answer

Comment: I think you should explain where you put this file, how it gets included in WordPress and all the steps needed to get this to work. Your example is using JSX and that doesn't work out of the box in browsers.

Answer (score 8):

I took a look at [Richard Tape's article](https://richardtape.com/2018/10/05/add-a-custom-sidebar-panel-to-gutenberg/) which required you create your own Gutenberg React component (which is likely the best, most customisable way to do it). But I also have **Advanced Custom Fields Pro** installed (it has to be [version 5.8.0-beta3](https://cornerstone.lndo.site/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group&page=acf-settings-info&tab=changelog)). That provides a much easier method to add a custom meta field to the Gutenberg sidebar.

**Create a new field in ACF Pro** and in the *Field group settings*, ensure you have the following settings configured:

1. Style: Standard (WP Metabox)
2. Position: Side

This has worked for me ( added a *Reading time* field). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/backward-compatibility/meta-box/
and
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

use $context = 'side'

Example:

```
add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box', 'My Meta Box', 'my_meta_box_callback',
    null, 'side', 'high',
    array(
        '__back_compat_meta_box' => true,
    )
);
```

Comment: This will add metabox, but not panel.