# How to add an entry to the Page/Post Settings Sidebar?

Tags: sidebar

Is it possible to add an entry to the [Page/Post Settings Sidebar](https://wordpress.org/support/article/settings-sidebar/)? In other words, can we add something here:

[image]

Notes:

- I do not want to add a [Block settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/). In other words, I would like to target the "Post" or "Page" tab, not the "Block" one.
- I do not want to [add an additional Sidebar](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/plugin-sidebar-0/plugin-sidebar-1-up-and-running/). I would like to plugin into the existing "Settings" sidebar.

Comment: Exactly! I found it too and answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been [posted](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327538/add-metabox-to-document-tab-in-gutenberg/361493) and [answered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327538/add-metabox-to-document-tab-in-gutenberg/361493#answer-361493):

Follow [Get a Sidebar up and Running](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/plugin-sidebar-0/plugin-sidebar-1-up-and-running/) from the WordPress doc, but use [PluginDocumentSettingPanel](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-edit-post/#plugindocumentsettingpanel) instead of PluginSidebar.